# Udin more than two apply() in one function

Tags: r

I have data like students responds in an exam.  I have wrote some codes to calculate the correct and false answers like

```
`ncorrect <- function(resp,keyt){
  cr <- sum(resp == keyt, na.rm = T)
  return(cr)
}


nfalse <- function(resp,keyt){
  fl <- sum(resp != keyt, na.rm = T)
  return(fl)
}`
```

I want to bind these datas in my dataframe and wrote a code like

```
checkscores <- function(frame){
 frame$ncorrect <- apply(frame,1,ncorrect,keyt=frame[1,]) 
 frame$nfalse <- apply(frame,1,nfalse,keyt=frame[1,])
  return(frame)
}
```

but the line `frame$nfalse <- apply(frame,1,nfalse,keyt=frame[1,])`  use frame as previous line so that it gives the data with an addition +1.  How can I fix this ? thanks for your attention

Edit:

```
       V2   V3   V4 V5   V6 ncorrect nfalse
key      A    B    C  D    A        5      0
ahmet    A <NA> <NA>  D    A        3      0
canan    A    D <NA>  D    A        3      1
kemal    D    C    B  A    A        1      4
meral    A    B    C  D    D        4      1
ziya     C    C    C  D    A        3      2
mine  <NA>    A    C  D <NA>        2      1






       V2   V3   V4 V5   V6 ncorrect nfalse
key      A    B    C  D    A        5      0
ahmet    A <NA> <NA>  D    A        3      1
canan    A    D <NA>  D    A        3      2
kemal    D    C    B  A    A        1      5
meral    A    B    C  D    D        4      2
ziya     C    C    C  D    A        3      3
mine  <NA>    A    C  D <NA>        2      2
```

the first one is expected , and the second one is what I get.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: @AnuragN.Sharma Could you please look at the edit ?

Comment: if either of the answers here solve your problem, please click on the checkmark by the answer to accept it. If not, please edit your question (or possibly leave a comment) to explain why they don't.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your data is stored in `dat`, one can use builtin functions to achieve the desired information. First I'll assume that the data is stored in `dat`, and that this is either a `tibble`, `data.frame` or `data.table`. And I assume that then name of each student is in column 1, with the correct answers in the first row.
In order to perform the calculations we can abuse that we can compare a matrix with another `M1 == M2` and obtain a logical matrixas output.

```
correct_test_answers <- dat[1, 2:6]
test_answers <- dat[-1, 2:6]
correct_answers <- rowSums(as.matrix(test_answers) == matrix(correct_test_answers, 
                                                             ncol = 5, 
                                                             nrow = nrow(test_answers)),
                           na.rm = TRUE)
not_answers <- rowSums(is.na(test_answers), na.rm = TRUE)
wrong_answers <- 5 - correct_answers - not_answers
dat[-1, c('correct', 'wrong', 'not_answers')] <- data.frame(correct_answers, 
                                                            wrong_answers, 
                                                            not_answers)
dat
      V1   V2   V3   V4 V5   V6 correct wrong not_answers
1:   key    A    B    C  D    A      NA    NA          NA
2: ahmet    A <NA> <NA>  D    A       3     0           2
3: canan    A    D <NA>  D    A       1     3           1
4: kemal    D    C    B  A    A       1     4           0
5: meral    A    B    C  D    D       0     5           0
6:  ziya    C    C    C  D    A       0     5           0
7:  mine <NA>    A    C  D <NA>       2     1           2
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the second apply in checkscores evaluate frame which has first wow with the score of correct answers calculated by the first apply. You can create an auxiliar df inside the checkscore to be used in apply.

```
checkscores <- function(frame){
 aux <- frame
 frame$ncorrect <- apply(aux,1,ncorrect,keyt=frame[1,]) 
 frame$nfalse <- apply(aux,1,nfalse,keyt=frame[1,])
 return(frame)
}
```